# Perl Regex: Cut and Paste

Tags: regex, perl

I'm attempting to use perl to edit a file, essentially to cut and paste content within the file. However, it appears I've incorrectly constructed the regex. I'd appreciate help in sorting it out. The substitution command *should* cut cut the content after `export PATH=$PATH` up to but *not* including `# THIS IS LAST`, and paste that content before `export PATH=$PATH`

Perl Command:
`perl -i -pe 's;(export PATH.*\n)(.*)(\# THIS IS LAST!\n);$2$1$3;' bashrc`

Current bashrc:

```
export TERM=xterm
export PATH=$PATH
export BREW_HOME=/home/dev/.linuxbrew 
export ANACONDA_HOME=/home/dev/.anaconda3

# THIS IS LAST!
```

Desired bashrc:

```
export TERM=xterm 
export BREW_HOME=/home/dev/.linuxbrew 
export ANACONDA_HOME=/home/dev/.anaconda3
export PATH=$PATH

# THIS IS LAST!
```

Comment: Re "_cut the content after `export PATH=$PATH`_" ... does this really mean "after **the line** `export ..`" ?  (What my answer does -- it swaps that whole line with what follows it)

Comment: @zdim: I mean starting with subsequent line, i.e. `export BREW_HOME...` Essentially, I want to cut everything **between** the lines `export PATH=$PATH` and `# THIS LINE IS LAST!` and paste that content **before** `export PATH=$PATH`. Does that help clarify intent?

Comment: Yes, that's how I took it.  Fixed my answer, to account for that tricky empty line which shouldn't move :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match across multiple lines you need to have the whole file in a scalar

```
perl -0777 -pe's/(export PATH.*?\n)(.*?)(?=\n?# THIS IS LAST)/$2$1/s' input.txt
```

where [-0777](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) enables "slurp" mode, and `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind).

The `\n?` is in the lookahead to include the optional empty line that shouldn't be consumed, since that line shouldn't be moved. Then the previous pattern need be non-greedy, too. This protects a single preceding empty line, any others are matched and swapped.

Comment: @Miller  Thank you for comments